# Set focus on another control when a key pressed without code-behind

Tags: wpf, focus, controls

I'm implementing something like an autosuggestion control: I have a user control that contains a `TextBox` and a `ListBox`. When the user enters text I'm handing it with `System.Windows.Interactivity` behaviors and filling the `ListBox` with some values...

Everything works fine... but I want to enable the user to select items in the `ListBox` (i.e. to set `Focus` on the `ListBox`) when the down arrow key is pressed.

I know that it is possible to handle the `KeyPressDown` event of the `TextBox` in the code-behind .cs file but how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already use Interactivity that should not be much of an issue, just implement your own `TriggerAction` that has the properties `Key` & `TargetName` to indentify when and what to focus. Set it in an `EventTrigger` for `PreviewKeyDown`.

Sample implementation & use:

```
<TextBox>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
            <t:KeyDownFocusAction Key="Down"
                                  Target="{Binding ElementName=lbx}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
<ListBox Name="lbx" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" />
```

```
class KeyDownFocusAction : TriggerAction<UIElement>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Key", typeof(Key), typeof(KeyDownFocusAction));
    public Key Key
    {
        get { return (Key)GetValue(KeyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(KeyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Target", typeof(UIElement), typeof(KeyDownFocusAction), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    public UIElement Target
    {
        get { return (UIElement)GetValue(TargetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TargetProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key))
        {
            Target.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Tested it and it works, note that `KeyDown` does not because the arrow keys are intercepted and marked as handled by the TextBox.

Comment: Thank you, H.B. I think it'll work - I'll try it and report about the results

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can avoid it

What's wrong with capturing the `KeyDown` event of the TextBox and if it's an Up or Down arrow key, just trigger the `ListBox.KeyDown` event in the code behind?

I see no reason not to use code-behind in MVVM if it is to provide view-specific functionality such as focus

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the one from `H.B.`, and adds support for checking to see if the Ctrl key is pressed. This means it can handle keycombinations such as Ctrl-F for find.

### XAML

```
<TextBox>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
        <t:KeyDownFocusAction Key="Down" Ctrl="True"
                              Target="{Binding ElementName=lbx}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
<ListBox Name="lbx" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" />
```

### Namespaces

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

See [help on adding `System.Windows.Interactivity`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360209/how-to-add-system-windows-interactivity-to-project).

### DependencyProperty

```
public class KeyDownFocusAction : TriggerAction<UIElement>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Key", typeof(Key), typeof(KeyDownFocusAction));
    public Key Key
    {
        get { return (Key)GetValue(KeyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(KeyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CtrlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Ctrl", typeof(bool), typeof(KeyDownFocusAction));
    public bool Ctrl
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(CtrlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CtrlProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Target", typeof(UIElement), typeof(KeyDownFocusAction), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    public UIElement Target
    {
        get { return (UIElement)GetValue(TargetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TargetProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key))
        {
            if (Ctrl == true)
            {
                if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
                {
                    Target.Focus();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```